# Unable to create admin user in InfluxDB

Tags: docker, influxdb

I have to create an ADMIN role user of InfluxDB at the time of initializing docker container. My script is:

```
echo "=> Starting InfluxDB ..."
exec influxd

#wait for the startup of influxdb
RET=1
while [[ RET -ne 0 ]]; do
    echo "=> Waiting for confirmation of InfluxDB service startup ..."
    sleep 3
    curl -k ${API_URL}/ping 2> /dev/null
    RET=$?
done
echo ""

RUN su- curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:8086/query' --data-urlencode "q=CREATE USER admin WITH PASSWORD 'password' WITH ALL PRIVILEGES"
```

Above script does create the user but issue is that the role of the user is **not set to ADMIN**. I need a user with ADMIN role. What can be the possible issue here ? Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Use env variables (applicable for official InfluxDB docker image https://hub.docker.com/_/influxdb):

> INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER
>
> The name of the admin user to be created. If this is unset, no admin user is created.
> INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD
>
> The password for the admin user configured with INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER. If this is unset, a random password is generated and printed to standard out.

Comment: But i dont want to use environment variables. I want to create the admin user immediately after the container is up and have to do this with a script. Any help on that @Jan Garaj ?